# Unsafe assignment of an `any` value when using in to confirm object property in unknown

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am trying to write some code to handle errors in a JSON:API response.

```
const handleResponseErrors = (
  response: unknown,
) => {
  if (response && typeof response === 'object' && 'data' in response) {
    const { data } = response;
    // Ensure we have a data object.
    if (data && typeof data === 'object') {
      // Throw errors returned by Drupal.
      if ('errors' in data && Array.isArray(data.errors) && 0 in data.errors) {
        if (typeof data.errors[0] === 'object' && 'detail' in data.errors[0]) {
          const { detail } = data.errors[0];
          if (typeof detail === 'string') {
            throw new Error(detail);
          }
        }
      }
```

I'm confused because `@typescript-eslint` gives an error for the line `const { detail } = data.errors[0];`:

> Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.

So I tried this:

```
if (
  typeof data.errors[0] === 'object' &&
  'detail' in data.errors[0] &&
  typeof data.errors[0].detail === 'string'
) {
```

This also gives an error:

> Unsafe member access .detail on an `any` value.

The [docs on no-unsafe-assignment](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-assignment.md) suggest typing the object.  But in my case, I'm trying to work with `unknown` to be extra safe so that my runtime code is not reliant on types to process the response.  I thought by using `property in object` and `typeof object.property === type` I could get eslint to understand that the type is not `any`, but this isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the linter; the `any` assignment is valid.

Typescript infers that the entire `data.errors` as `any[]` from the `Array.isArray(data.errors)` check. This inference does not change
after the subsequent check that looks for the 'detail' prop of `data.errors[0]`. This inference is a [Typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43865) [feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17002).

To prevent the errors thrown by the linter, you'll need to override the `isArray` method's interface:

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
  isArray(arg: any): arg is ReadonlyArray<unknown> | Array<unknown>;
}
```

This will change the type of `data.errors` to `readonly unknown[] | unknown[]`.